# Co-existent classes in C++

Tags: c++, class, design-patterns, object

What I need is to create two classes, that uses each other.

For example:

`Class A` contains objects of type `Class B`, and `Class B` contain objects of type `Class A`

But, when I compile, This is what happens: "error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'Map' with no type"

I modified my classes, to keep the Header (.h) file separated, but it didn't solved.

Perhaps, it's a basic question, but I don't know the keyword to search on google...

Code:

Cell.h:

```
Class Cell
{
public:
    Map *map;
}
```

Map.h:

```
Class Map
{
public:
    Cell *cell;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "contain"?  Clearly, `A` and `B` can't have instances of each other as members...

Comment: Yes they can @OliCharlesworth ...

Comment: @IvanSeidel: They definitely can't, because that would lead to an infinite recursion.  They can, however, members that *point to* or *reference* instances of each other (e.g. via a `map`).

Comment: You posted links to code, not code.  A good question has a simplified version of your code that still demonstrates the problem you want discussed.  See also http://sscce.org .

Comment: @IvanSeidel They can't contain instances of each other.  Best they can do is hold references or pointers to other instances.  It's very different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `class A` contains a `class B` and `class B` also contains a `class A` then no, you cannot do that.

```
class B; // forward declaration of name only. Compiler does not know how much
         // space a B needs yet.

class A {
    private:
        B b; // fail because we don't know what a B is yet.
};

class B {
    private:
        A a;
};
```

Even if this would work there would be no way to construct an instance of either.

```
B b; // allocates space for a B
     // which needs to allocate space for its A
     // which needs to allocate space for its B
     // which needs to allocate space for its A
     // on and on...
```

The can however contain pointers (or references) to each other.

```
class B; // forward declaration tells the compiler to expect a B type.

class A {
    private:
        B* b; // only allocates space for a pointer which size is always
              // known regardless of type.

};

class B {
    private:
        A* a;
};
```

Answer (score 3):

You want *forward declaration* and pointers.

```
//a.h
class B; //forward declare than a class B, exist somewhere, although it is not completely defined.

class A{
 map<string,B*> mapOfB;
};

//b.h
class A; //forward declare than a class A, exist somewhere, although it is not completely defined.
class B{
 map<string,A*> mapOfA;
}
```

and in your .cxx you would actually include the necessary headers

```
//a.cxx
#include "b.h"
A::A(){ /* do stuff with mapOfB */ }

//b.cxx
#include "a.h"
B::B(){ /* do stuff with mapOfA */ }
```

Comment: Shared pointers would be a better option here, though be careful about circular references.

Comment: Yea but just keeping it light/simple as example

Comment: ahh man come one guys... its not a big deal. Too much clutter for a simplistic example. Plus user hasn't specified the availability of C++11 or boost ...

Answer (score 2):

The problem in your case is that you have recursive includes. `Cell.h` includes `Map.h` which includes `Cell.h`. Instead of including like this just forward declare the classes:

In `Cell.h`:

```
class Map;

class Cell
{
    // ...
}
```

In `Map.h`:

```
class Cell;

class Map
{
    // ...
}
```